# How do I serve static files from my react build in a docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am new to docker and building projects. I am trying to put my react app in a docker container with nginx, but when I run the container I get a blank page with 404 errors for the files in the static dir. I basically followed this article: https://blog.aevitas.co.uk/running-react-on-docker-with-nginx/

I used create-react-app and I haven't changed anything in webpack. This is how my files look:

Dockerfile:

```
#Node image
FROM node:8.11.3 as builder
#Create app directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.default
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

default.config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;


  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the article https://blog.aevitas.co.uk/running-react-on-docker-with-nginx/, and what I did:

1 - `npx create-react-app sample`

2 - Inside the sample directory I created a directory nginx with default.conf

3 - Change `COPY nginx/default.conf` to `COPY ./nginx/default.conf`

4 - Build image: `docker build -t react-app .`

5 - Run: `docker run --name react-app-run -p 8080:80 react-app:latest`

6 - Access: localhost:8080

Working perfectly!

Comment: Hmm it still didn't work for me. Here is my repo if you don't mind taking a look: https://github.com/hpufo/TaskManager

Comment: I cloned your repo locally and:  run the same commands above e run perfectly, see if your ports are opened, try a different port or different laptop/machine.